# Why windbg cannot read symbols from my pdb file?

Tags: visual-studio, security, debugging, windbg, ollydbg

my pdb file `MFCLibrary1.pdb` was genereted by virtual studio 2017, I place it in its origin directory `G:\MFCLibrary1\Debug\`, I set symbol path and windbg can load it normally, however, I cannot read any symbol information with `x MFCLibrary1!*` command, as the fllowing picture show:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the source  in the source path, but it also cannot switch to source mode debug! Why?

Comment: I use `symchk` to check the pdbfile  and the MFCLibrary1.dll, it success, however it cannot work fine in windbg! Why?

Comment: My guess is that `/DEBUG:FASTLINK` (the new default for VS2017 when just specifying `/DEBUG`) is generating symbols that your version of `dbghelp.dll` cannot understand. Similar issues have [been reported before](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/36255/chromes-base-unittests-fails-with-vs-2017-due-to-s.html). If upgrading to the latest Windbg doesn't help, see if specifying `/DEBUG:FULL` helps, at the expense of longer link times.

Comment: Thank you, Sean Cline. Your answer  is the perfect solution to my problem. You help me a lot, Thank you again from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: @SeanCline, Since your comment resolve this issue, could you please convert your comment to the answer? This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we could close this thread.

Answer (score 4):

`link.exe` has historically been pretty slow for big projects and it turns out most of that slowness was from generating the PDB file.

Visual Studio 2017 now defaults to using a new switch, [`/DEBUG:FASTLINK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info), which generates a minimal PDB file and leaves the rest of the debugging information inside the `.obj` files.

The obvious benefit of this option is the [2x to 4x improvement in link time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/faster-c-build-cycle-in-vs-15-with-debugfastlink/), but it comes with some downsides.

**Downside #1** - The PDB file for debug builds no longer contains all of the information required for symbolic debugging.

If you plan to debug your project on a different machine from the one that built it, you'll still need to generate a FULL symbol file.

This can be done in one of two ways:

1. An existing FASTLINK PDB can be converted to a FULL PDB from Visual Studio's menu by running *Build->Build full program database file for solution*. [image: Build full program database]
2. It can be permanently changed by setting the *Generate Debug Info* switch to `/DEBUG:FULL` on the project's *Linker->Debugging* property page. [image: Linker property page]

**Downside #2** - Older tools, especially those using `dbghelp.dll` like WinDbg, don't understand the new FASTLINK symbol file format.

Some versions refuse to load FASTLINK symbols, others crash or hang. It's best update to the most recent version.

On my machine, FASTLINK symbols work fine with WinDbg version 10.0.15063.137, so updating your debugging tools to that version or higher should work.

If you cannot move to a new version of a debugging tool, for whatever reason, then generating a FULL PDB as described above is the next best option. Unfortunately, doing this, you won't see the improved link times that came with Visual Studio 2017.